# What is this extension on mu web URL?? It leads to a blank page. what is causing it/?

Tags: urls

The following extension has been added to my web URL and traffic sent there. Its a blank page. What is causing it and to what should it refer to?

?et_pb_preview=true&et_pb_preview=true&et_pb_preview_nonce=982e2f506f&iframe_id=et-fb-preview-1580807228632-78

Comment: It looks like a preview link from Divi. If you copied a link from a preview window it will copy a link to the preview version, which will look like that. You must have added a link on your site somewhere that you had copied from a preview. You'll need to find it and remove it, but there's not enough information in the question to be able to say more than that.

Comment: Thanks for that quick answer Jacob.

Comment: i can't really provide any more info because i don't know where is came from either. what I can add is that it has created several similar urls with the final large number at the end being different in each one. also, for some reason it has attracted lots of hits from people in Hong Kong who hit this page and since its blank they quickly left. Does this help.??

Comment: Not really. If you can see what the referral url is for people visiting that page you an see what page likely has incorrect links on it.